# Linked image became embedded when trying to improve suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, images

The suggested edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/979182 (both in rendered and markdown diffs) shows a URL to an image:

> ```
> Screenshot of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoMlt.png
> ```

I wondered why the screenshot had not been embedded, so I clicked on Improve, only to find that the code had changed to the following:

> ```
> Screenshot of output:
>  ![enter image description here][1]
>
>
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUdRB.png
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13343811/revisions also shows it embedded and shows the above in the markdown diff.

Is there some sort of auto-conversion going on? I couldn't find anything relevant in the [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Strongly related: ["improve" option for suggested edits plays leapfrog with consecutive suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no auto-conversion. You're simply seeing the source of [revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13343811/revisions) when you hit "improve", instead of the source of the suggested edit you expected to see. The suggested edit had already been approved when you hit the button, so your "improve" was essentially just a normal edit of the post at that point.

This is rather confusing, and I've previous [reported a similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132423/improve-option-for-suggested-edits-plays-leapfrog-with-consecutive-suggestions). This case is a little different in that there was only one suggested edit involved, but both situations could be fixed by letting you know that the suggested edit had already been approved. I actually thought this already happened in the case you're describing, but it seems not.

Comment: I was not only seeing the source of the approved edit (which was revision 5), but the subsequent edit too! Very confusing. Thanks for clearing that up!